# My unittests don't work due to connection already closed

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-unittest

I am trying to do unittests but it does not work.

Here is my file of tests :

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def authenticate(self):
        useremail = 'myemail@email.fr'
        userpassword = 'password'

        c = self.client
        loggedin = c.login(email=useremail, password=userpassword)
        self.assertTrue(loggedin, "Not logged")

    def test_1(self):

        self.authenticate()
        c = self.client
        data = {
            'searched': 'companylimit'
        }
        response = c.post('/djangoproject/get_information/', data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        logger.info(pformat(json.loads(response.content)['result']))
        self.assertIs(type(json.loads(response.content)['result']), int)

        time.sleep(5)

    def test_2(self):

        self.authenticate()

        c = self.client
        data = {
            'searched': 'management',
            'requested': User.objects.filter(is_active=True)[0].uniqueid
        }
        response = c.post('/djangoproject/get_information/', data, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        logger.info(pformat(json.loads(response.content)['result']))
        if type(json.loads(response.content)['result']) == list:
            self.assertIs(type(json.loads(response.content)['result']), list)
        else:
            self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.content)['result'], "")
```

I got `django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed` because I have 2 tests whereas with just one test it works.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT  :Here is the full traceback :

```
ERROR: test_2 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 234, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 222, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests/test_3.py", line 47, in test_2
    self.authenticate()
  File "/tests/test_3.py", line 26, in authenticate
    loggedin = c.login(email=useremail, password=userpassword)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 594, in login
    user = authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 16, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 393, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 234, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 234, in _cursor
    return self._prepare_cursor(self.create_cursor(name))
  File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 222, in create_cursor
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

Comment: can you share your complete traceback?

Comment: for what is worth, there's a "lesser complicated" way of doing using by logging in the user inside the `setup` function and use `self.force_login(my_user_object)` to login.

Comment: It does not work I got that : `'SimpleTest' object has no attribute '_login'
`

Comment: can you show your completest test file? also, what commands are you using to run the test?

Comment: Are you using `django.test.TestCase` or `unittest.TestCase`?